# Joomla Blog article layout order problem

Tags: joomla

I'm having problems with a Joomla install (problem exists in both 1.5.13 and 1.5.15) that won't order articles in a category or section blog layout.

I've tried setting the sort order on the layout manually to all the different sort options but it has no effect.

Ordering on the front page works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to make these changes in the Menu Item configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Enable Custom Ordering...

install-climber.blogspot.com/2011/09/set-custom-articles-order-parameter-or.html

Answer (score 0):

In the options for the menu item (i.e. when you click the item name), look on the right hand side and click "Parameters (Advanced)".

You should set *Category Order* to "No, order by Primary Order only" and *Primary Order* to "Default" (or "Most recent first" if that doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

If a Category is tuned to be shown in several columns (f.e. 2), but only 1 column fits in template, the soring may be broken.